# Can I compress an if statement using linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

In sql, I can make an if statement like the following
If MY_STATE in (1,2,3,4)

In C# I have to type
if(MY_STATE == STATE.CT || MY_STATE == STATE.MA || MY_STATE == STATE.VA || MY_STATE == STATE.RI)

This is obviously more clunky. Can I use LINQ to mimic the "in" statement of sql?

I'm looking for something like
if(MY_STATE in (STATE.CT, STATE.MA, STATE.VA, STATE.RI))

Comment: The LINQ syntax that looks like SQL can only make IEnumerables in C#. What you want is a boolean result, so the closest you're going to get is like (new[] { State.CT, State.MA }).Contains(myState). This has a lot more overhead than just writing the if-statement; unless your list of acceptable states is going to be dynamic at runtime, there's really no point in doing this.

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider this. I have no desire to change something from compile time to runtime just to make it look pretty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if (new [] {State.CT, State.MA, State.VA, State.RI}.Contains(myState)) {
  // There you go
}
```

Comment: It looks nice. I like easy to read code that is even easy to maintain. Does somebody knows how the performance is in comparison to the switch statement?

Comment: Worse. Switch and if statements are basically comparisons and jumps. This is creating an array and doing a loop, compare, break.
Does it matter though? Depends on your usecase. Measure it :)

Answer (score 7):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool EqualsAny<T>(this T comparer, params T[] values)
    {
        foreach (T t in values)
            if (comparer.Equals(t))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
if (myState.EqualsAny(State.CT, State.MA, State.VA, State.RI)) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's actually not necessary: You already have .Any() on IEnumerable<T>. So if(new [] {"CT", "MA", "VA", "RI"}.Any(e => e == value)) {} would do the same.

Comment: But you have to type out the new[] { ... } and the lambda expression each time.

Comment: Good point. Technically it should be the same (speed). You could use the .Any in your EqualsAny() though. ;-) I digress. It works just as well and is a valid solution of course.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use Contains, which maps onto the SQL IN.  I'm assuming State is an enum and stored as an integer.

```
var states = new int[] { (int)State.CT, (int)State.MA, (int)State.VA, (int)State.RI };

var query = db.States.Where( s => states.Contains( s.State ) );
```

Comment: You were faster ;-) I don't like the int cast though, but that's probably just me.

Comment: I'm not sure that Contains on an `IEnumerable<State>`, when the field on the DB is an int will work without the cast and I don't think you could cast the DB field to an instance of the enum.  I could be wrong, though.  I didn't check it.  If so, then I agree that making it an array of the enum type and dropping the cast would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ I would use the switch statement.

```
switch (MY_STATE) {
  case STATE.CT:
  case.STATE.MA:
  case.STATE.VA:
  case.STATE.RI:
    ....
    break;
}
```

just jotted it down from memory. So you might correct some syntax issues.

Comment: This is one of the few things that really ticks me off about C#. You can do this in C++ but you can't do this in C#. I have no idea why.

Comment: @diadem: what do you mean? C# does have a switch statement.

Comment: You can in c# if my_state is an enum or an int.

Comment: You mean, that you can't use 'switch'?

Comment: @diadem:  this will work in C# as well.  When there is no code in the case statements, you can stack them to allow fall-through just like the example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Scott got it right: diadem was probably confused about needing a break; or goto someOtherCase; - which isn't needed in this sample.

Comment: You are right. I got confused for a second - the limitation is that you need a break before you have another set of case statements, unlike C++.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
    enum MyEnum
    {
        A, B, C, D
    }

    // ...
    MyEnum e = MyEnum.A;
    if (new []{ MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B }.Contains(e))
       Console.WriteLine("Yeah!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own extension method to do that:

```
static bool IsOneOf<T>(this T value, params T[] set)
{
    return set.Contains(value);
}
```

Usage: `MY_STATE.IsOneOf(STATE_A, STATE_B, STATE_C)`

(It's slower at runtime, though. It has to create a temporary array and all parameters to IsOneOf have to be evaluated)