# Finding out if an int is equal to any member of a set of ints?

Tags: c#

I know I can do it like this:

```
if(myint == 1 || myint == 2 || myint ==3) //etc...
```

But I feel like there must be a more efficient way to code this. Is there a way to possibly make a statement like this work?

```
if(myint.Contains(1 || 2 || 3 || 4))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining multiple conditional expressions in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390138/combining-multiple-conditional-expressions-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Servy you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close, try the following.
It will take a collection and return `true` if your `int` is in the collection:

```
if (new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Contains(myint))
    //Do something
```

`new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` represents an array of integers.

The `Contains` method is an extension of `IEnumerable<T>` and will be available to anything that implements it.

Answer (score 14):

you can do inverse

```
new List<int>{1,2,3,4}.Contains(myInt)
```

Note that there is also [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb534972.aspx), but `Contains` would work for `.net 2.0` too.

Comment: You don't need List<T>, any IEnumerable<T> will do, including a plain old array.

Comment: +1. Note if set is constant and big enough `HashSet` would give better performance.

Comment: Note that this syntax requires C# >= 3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx